# My ex changed my authorization password. I am not at all tech savvy by any means and have no idea what to do

Tags: password

I have a toshiba satellite laptop that I purchased from a friend while in a relationship with my ex. during our breakup he changed my password and now I can't authorize any important changes that are needed for upgrades, deleting files etc. Unfortunately for me he is much more familiar with computers than I am and I'm not even sure if this is the only change or problem he created . I've tried many suggestions that I found online including deleting the keyring and related files with absolutely no success. Can someone please help me out.

Comment: See the steps outlined here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LostPassword

Answer (score 0):

Sure, and I'm sorry to hear about your Ex. I actually have the same laptop-It used to run Windows Vista (Worst. Operating System. EVER!) and I had a similar Issue. First, boot up in Recovery Mode. If you have a single-boot (Ubuntu is the only operating system on your computer), to get the boot menu to show, you have to hold down the Shift key during bootup.

If you have a dual-boot (Ubuntu is installed next to Windows, another Linux operating system, or Mac OS X; and you choose at boot time which operating system to boot into), the boot menu should appear without the need to hold down the Shift key. Now, select Recovery Mode. After you select recovery mode and wait for all the boot-up processes to finish, you'll be presented with a few options. In this case, you want the Drop to root shell prompt option so press the Down arrow to get to that option, and then press Enter to select it.

The root account is the ultimate administrator and can do anything to the Ubuntu installation (including erase it), so please be careful with what commands you enter in the root terminal.

In recent versions of Ubuntu, the filesystem is mounted as read-only, so you need to enter the follow command to get it to remount as read-write, which will allow you to make changes:

mount -o rw,remount /
To reset the password, type

passwd username
where username is the username you want to reset. In this case, I want to reset Susan's password, so I type
passwd susan
You'll then be prompted for a new password. When you type the password you will get no visual response acknowledging your typing. Your password is still being accepted. Just type the password and hit Enter when you're done. You'll be prompted to retype the password. Do so and hit Enter again.

Now the password should be reset. Type

exit
to return to the recovery menu.
After you get back to the recovery menu, select resume normal boot, and use Ubuntu as you normally would—only this time, you actually know the password!
Source: http://psychocats.net/ubuntu/resetpassword

Good Luck!